# string array with a if

Tags: arrays, string, google-bigquery

from an array string created with a `FROM` i want to include an `IF` condition to it but bigquery is telling me that cannot be possible. I am having the following error `Syntax error: Expected ")" but got keyword FROM` whenever i am trying to do something like:

```
SELECT 
  IF(TRUE, STRING_AGG(x, ' | ')
  FROM UNNEST([
    IF(FALSE, 'new_customer', NULL), 
    IF(TRUE, 'new_customer_vertical', NULL),
    IF(TRUE, 'new_customer_expedition', NULL),
    IF(FALSE, 'new_customer_pandapro', NULL)
  ]) AS x, NULL)
```

If i remove the `IF` condition, is passing

```
SELECT 
  STRING_AGG(x, ' | ')
  FROM UNNEST([
    IF(FALSE, 'new_customer', NULL), 
    IF(TRUE, 'new_customer_vertical', NULL),
    IF(TRUE, 'new_customer_expedition', NULL),
    IF(FALSE, 'new_customer_pandapro', NULL)
  ]) AS x
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure below is what you try to do, but you looks want a scalar subquery in **IF()** function.

```sql
SELECT IF(TRUE, -- some condition
          (SELECT STRING_AGG(x, ' | ')
             FROM UNNEST([
               IF(FALSE, 'new_customer', NULL), 
               IF(TRUE, 'new_customer_vertical', NULL),
               IF(TRUE, 'new_customer_expedition', NULL),
               IF(FALSE, 'new_customer_pandapro', NULL)
             ]) AS x
          ), -- IF true
          NULL) -- IF false
```

Comment: This is the correct syntax OP needs to follow . Lucas is clearly missing the basic syntax for [`IF`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/conditional_expressions#if) statement i.e `IF(expr, true_result, else_result)`. In this case `true_result` is nothing but a result from a `subquery`.

Comment: Agreed, and Lucas seems to know **IF**, but simply wrote it as a psuedo code for simplicty.